# How to bind nested properties bidirectional in JavaFX?

Tags: java, binding, javafx, javabeans

How to bind nested properties bidirectional in JavaFX?

For example, I have an object `p` which has propeties `prop1` and `prop2`, which in turn have properties `value` both.

How to bind them bidirectional, so that they will constrain equal?

```
package tests.javafx.beans.binding;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class Try_BindNested {

    public static class Nested {

        private SimpleDoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public double getValue() {
            return value.get();
        }

        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value.set(value);
        }

        public SimpleDoubleProperty valueProperty() {
            return value;
        }

    }


    public static class Parent {

        private SimpleObjectProperty<Nested> prop1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<Nested>();

        private SimpleObjectProperty<Nested> prop2 = new SimpleObjectProperty<Nested>();

        public Nested getProp1() {
            return prop1.get();
        }

        public void setProp1(Nested prop1) {
            this.prop1.set(prop1);
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Nested> prop1Property() {
            return prop1;
        }

        public Nested getProp2() {
            return prop2.get();
        }

        public void setProp2(Nested prop1) {
            this.prop2.set(prop1);
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Nested> prop2Property() {
            return prop2;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Parent p = new Parent();

        // how to bind bidirectional p.prop1.value = p.prop2.value?


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to handle changes to the "intermediate" property (i.e. `p.prop2.value` is updated if you do `p.setProp1(...);`) then there's no way to do this directly with bindings; you have to use a pair of listeners.

Using the standard JavaFX properties API:

```
ObservableDoubleValue prop1Value = Bindings.selectDouble(p.prop1Property(), "value");
ObservableDoubleValue prop2Value = Bindings.selectDouble(p.prop2Property(), "value");
prop1Value.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldVal, Number newValue) {
        p.getProp2().setValue(newValue);
   }
});
prop2Value.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldVal, Number newValue) {
        p.getProp1().setValue(newValue);
   }
});
```

The `Bindings.select` methods are a bit ugly (they rely on reflection and are not type safe); additionally in early JavaFX 8 versions they spew out all sorts of warnings if any of the intermediate properties are null (despite this being a supported use case according to the API docs). You might look at the [EasyBind framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) if this becomes an issue. You would still need the "double listener" idiom here too, though.

The reason there's no "built-in" bidirectional binding for this case is that it's ambiguous as to how to update the properties. In general, you might want something like `p.getProp1().setValue(newVal);`, or you might want to change the intermediate property: `p.setProp1(new Nested(newVal));`

Finally, you might need to be careful doing this with floating point types. The reason you don't end up with infinite recursion with the code above is that the `set` method in `DoubleProperty` checks to see if a change really occurs before notifying change listeners. If the value involves any computation, you risk rounding errors creating a situation where the property's check for equality fails incorrectly, and so you could end up with a nice StackOverflowError. If your value property does anything more complex than simply storing the value, you might want to guard the calls to `setValue` with a tolerance:

```
private static final double TOLERANCE = 1e-16 ; // or some other suitable small number

prop1Value.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldVal, Number newValue) {
        if (Math.abs(p.getProp2.getValue() - newVal) > TOLERANCE) {
            p.getProp2().setValue(newValue);
        }
   }
});
```

and similarly in the other direction.